# Need help reading lines from a text file and adding them to an ArrayList

Tags: java

For my homework assignment, I'm supposed to create an ATM/Teller program which stores users accounts in a text file. I require help reading the text file and storing certain parts of it in an array list.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class GetData
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filefullofmoney.txt"));

    String strLine;
    int numberOfLines = 0;    
    while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    {
      numberOfLines++;
    }

    Database[] accounts = new Database[numberOfLines];
    String[] array1 = new String[3];

    int i;
    int j = 0;

    while (j < numberOfLines)
    {
      for (i=0; i < 2; i++)
      {
        array1[i] = in.readLine();     
      }
      accounts.add(new Database(array[0],array[1],array[2]));
    }
  }
}

class Database
{
  public String accountName;
  public int pin;
  public double balance;
}
```

The part I'm having trouble with is accounts.add(new Database(array[0],array[1],array[2]));

Basically my text file will be formatted in this way:

```
Account1 name
Account1 pin
Account1 balance
Account2 name
Account2 pin
Account2 balance
etc...
```

I want to be able to add the 3 lines of text for each account into one element on the arraylist.

I'm not sure how much of my could actually works because I can't get it to compile.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Uggh @ `try { ... } catch (IOException e) {}`.  If there is an exception you won't know what it is.

Comment: Is everything in one line in your text file? Or is each account on a new line?

EDIT: Okay, you updated your post

Comment: `in.readLine()` will always return null since you have read everything. You need to call `in.reset()` after reading the number of lines.

Comment: Already second year and still such a basic question... Wouldn't have expected it. May I ask what you do? High School or University? I have to decide in 1 year a half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few problems with your code are:

- You do not have a specified constructor for your `Database` class (which should be named `Account`).
- You do not substring the lines, so you get along all the "Database#" prefixes.

  - And may I ask why you even have the prefixes there? They seem superfluous.
- You do not cast the `string`s to the actual data types (`int` and `double`).
- You loop over the content twice when you only need to do so once.
- You do not have proper exception handling; you should never wrap everything in one `catch(Exception)`.

A possible solution to your code could be this (I have not tested if it actually works):

```java
private static String getLineContent(String value) {
    return value.substring(value.indexOf(' ') + 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader in;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filefullofmoney.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        // TODO: Handle the error with a nice error message.
        return;
    }

    List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();

    while (true) {
        try {
            String accountName = in.readLine();

            if (accountName == null) {
                // We have no new accounts. So we exit.
                break;
            }

            accountName = getLineContent(accountName);
            int pin = Integer.parseInt(getLineContent(in.readLine()));
            double balance = Double.parseDouble(getLineContent(in.readLine()));

            accounts.add(new Account(accountName, pin, balance));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // TODO: Handle the error with a nice message saying that the file is malformed.
        }
    }
}

class Account {

    public String accountName;
    public int pin;
    public double balance;

    public Account(String accountName, int pin, double balance) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
        this.pin = pin;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: With your code, and every time I've tried to use an ArrayList, I get the error `cannot find symbol` `symbol : class ArrayList` `location: class GetData`

Comment: Never mind, I realized I forgot to import ArrayList and List into the program. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How would I retrieve values from this ArrayList after the program grabs them from the text file? Say if I wanted to verify the users pin?

Comment: @naneek

Use an `Iterator` (easiest way)

`Iterator<Account> i = list.iterator()`
`while (i.hasNext()) {`
`int pin = i.next().pin;`
`}`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `array1` and `array` choose one and it will compile.

Also you should combine those two while loops.  **Hint:** you don't need to know the `numberOfLines`.

Comment: Thanks, just fixed that part.

Comment: No problem, download Netbeans or Eclipse and it will check that for you.

Comment: Will do, was using a very basic IDE called Dr Java.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the class to `Account` instead of `Database`.

Then: the readLine() method will return the whole line, so:

```
Account1 Martijn Courteaux
```

will be one line. To take the name from it, you can use `String.substring()`:

```
String line = null; // Temp
String name = (line = in.readLine()).substring(line.indexOf(' '));
```

Do the same for the two other values:

```
int pin = Integer.parseInt((line = in.readLine()).substring(line.indexOf(' ')));
double balance = Double.parseDouble((line = in.readLine()).substring(line.indexOf(' ')));
```

Then use the values to pass them to the constructor:

```
accounts.add(new Account(name, pin, balance));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change

```
Database[] accounts = new Database[numberOfLines];
```

to be

```
ArrayList<String[]> accounts = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

then in the loop where you have

```
accounts.add(new Database(array[0],array[1],array[2]));
```

replace it with

```
accounts.add(array1);
```

Also, You never incremented J so your program will only get the first record.

If you have to use the Database class you have created, then you need to add a constructor that accepts those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filefullofmoney.txt"));
String line;
StringBuilder account = new StringBuilder();
List<Database> accounts = new ArrayList<Database>();

int count = 1;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
   account.append(line);
   account.append("---")

   if (count % 3 == 0) {
       Database data = new Database();
       data.accountName = account.toString().split("---")[0];
       data.pin = Integer.parseInt(account.toString().split("---")[1]);
       data.balance = Double.parseDouble(account.toString().split("---")[2]);
       accounts.add(data);
       account = new StringBuilder();
   }

   count++;
}

in.close();
```

**Explanation:**

The file is being read and every 3 lines (name, pin, balance), the data is added the the accounts List (% means modulus which returns the remainder when you divide). Since the pin and balance are not Strings, you have to parse the String to an integer and a double respectively.